# Custom spring-based rest API with Apache Knox gateway

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-security, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to do a POC in which I need to protect my cluster through Apache Knox, and my home-grown rest API will sit behind the Knox. How should user authentication work with Knox Ranger, and how will I protect my data access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the service.xml file. It should probably look like the much simpler version below. You would only need the more complex forms if you need to apply specific rules to specific parts of requests or responses. Note that ideally only one route would be required but the `**` in Knox means one or more path levels (not zero or more). So without the first route Knox wouldn't send requests to the root /Test_Web_App path to the service.

```
<service role="TEST_WEB_APP" name="Test_Web_App" version="0.0.1">
    <routes>
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/?**">
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/**?**">
    </routes>
</service>
```

If you wanted to be very specific about it this would be the equivalent. Here the `<rewrite apply="">` identifies a specific named rule in rewrite.xml and `<rewrite to="">` identifies what part of the request and or response the rule should be applied to.

```
<service role="TEST_WEB_APP" name="Test_Web_App" version="0.0.1">
    <routes>
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/?**">
          <rewrite apply="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App" to="request.url"/>
        </route>
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/**?**">
          <rewrite apply="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App/query" to="request.url"/>
        </route>
    </routes>
</service>
```

Now for the rewrite.xml. Yours was pretty close. All I added was a name (i.e. path) resulting in `{path=**}` to both the pattern and template of the second rule. In the `<rule pattern="">` this is used to give a name to the values that are extracted from the matched pattern. In `<rewrite template="">` the name is used to populate part of the URL being created with named values extracted from the matched pattern.

```
<rules>
    <rule dir="IN" name="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App" pattern="*://*:*/**/Test_Web_App/?{**}">
        <rewrite template="{$serviceUrl[TEST_WEB_APP]}/?{**}"/>
    </rule>

    <rule dir="IN" name="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App/query" pattern="*://*:*/**/Test_Web_App/{path=**}?{**}">
        <rewrite template="{$serviceUrl[TEST_WEB_APP]/{path=**}?{**}"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Note that the name "path" could be anything but "path" is used here as it represents the contextPath of the URL here.

Comment: Just to make sure that the "name" {path=**} is completely clear... During the processing of the rewrite rules, named variables are pulled from the incoming request (in this case the URL) and made available for the output of the rewrite (in this case the template). "{path=**}" means take all of the path elements from that position onward (one or more). You are then able to take that multi-element variable and populate the rewrite template with all or part of it - as needed. In this case, we want the entire path therefore it uses the variable name and the "{=**}" which represents all parts.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide a service definition for your custom REST API to Apache Knox. This will allow Knox to:

1. Recognize the URLs of the APIs incoming requests to your spring based service and be able to route requests to it
2. Know how to rewrite specific content such as URLs or other sensitive content from the responses to redirect the client back through gateway when appropriate.

See: http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-7-0/dev-guide.html#Service+Definition+Files within the developers guide for how to provide a service definition.

Once a service definition is in place, you just need to add a `<service>` element within a Knox topology to indicate where the actual spring based service is running. It would be something like this:

```
<service>
    <role>SERVICE</role>
    <url>http://url.to.your.service/v1/...</url>
</service>
```

This is also described in the same section of the developers guide.
You may also find the users guide helpful for additional examples of service declarations within the topology.

You can look at those examples and compare them to the service definition files for those existing services to see how service roles map. This will help you do the same for your own service.

For authentication details, see http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-7-0/user-guide.html#Authentication within the users guide for instructions in setting up LDAP based authentication. There are other authentication and federation provider implementations that may be of interest to you as well. You can find them within the users guide too.

Feel free to engage the dev or user email lists for Apache Knox as well.

Comment: hey Imccay thanks above links are really helped me i'll try that thanks again ...:)

Comment: hey I am trying to extend ServiceDeploymentContributorBase  class 
As mentioned in link http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-7-0/dev-guide.html#Service+Definition+Files but I am facing some issues with
UrlRewriteRulesDescriptor newRules = loadRulesFromClassPath();
but there is no Function definition named loadRulesFromClassPath and there is no doc for how to use the rewrite descriptor API. One more 
issue is there below function requires few more arguments but in the example it is not mentioned.  
addRewriteFilter( context, service, resource );
addDispatchFilter( context, service, resource);

Comment: i have contacted to dev and user mail list but if you know something about it then please help me ...actually there is no java doc available for that thats y i m so confused and i  m new to hadoop and knox  gateway

Comment: I think that we need to better understand why you are extending the ServiceDeploymentContributorBase. My intent for pointing you to that section was that there is a configuration based approach now that largely eliminates the need to create your own contributors now. I'd like to know whether this mechanism can't be used for your usecase or whether the docs need to better communicate the config based approach instead of requiring code.

Comment: hey i was doing that because I was following  link provided by you after researching i came to know that, that approach was used before knox 0.6.0 and i m using 0.6.0 but now my concern is  how to go for the config based approach i m following this link but after flowing this  also my service in not working http://kminder.github.io/knox/2015/11/16/adding-a-service-to-knox.html

Comment: The link that I sent should have taken you to the service definition files section. Clearly the older code based approach needs to be de-emphasized in order to make the docs more clear. Thanks. See my comments on your attached files.

Answer (score 0):

These are my 2 xml file please look in to it if i have mad any mistake or what else i need to do 
    **rewrite.xml

```
        <rule dir="IN" name="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App" pattern="*://*:*/**/Test_Web_App/?{**}">
            <rewrite template="{$serviceUrl[TEST_WEB_APP]}/?{**}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule dir="IN" name="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App/query" pattern="*://*:*/**/Test_Web_App/{**}?{**}">
            <rewrite template="{$serviceUrl[TEST_WEB_APP]/{**}?{**}"/>
        </rule>
         </rules>
**service.xml
<service role="TEST_WEB_APP" name="Test_Web_App" version="0.0.1">
    <routes>
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/**">
            <rewrite apply="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App/**" to="response.body" />
        </route>
        <route path="/Test_Web_App/**?**">
           <rewrite apply="TEST_WEB_APP/Test_Web_App/**?**" to="response.body"/>
    </routes>
</service>
```

Comment: Perhaps you just didn't copy it but the rules element is missing an opening tag in the above rewrite.xml file. I will continue to look at it though.

Comment: In addition, the second route element in the service.xml file seems to be missing a closing route tag.

Comment: Imccay sorry in original file both the things are there ...it was copy pasted really sorry for that